# What do the acronyms for tier 2 and tier 3 heavy weapon armors stand for?

Tags: xcom-2

The tier 2 and tier 3 heavy weapon armor names are acronyms (they have periods between each letter):

1. E.X.O. suit
2. W.A.R. suit

What do these acronyms stand for? I haven't found anything in-game that says anything about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XCOM has a habit of creating acronyms that make more sense as the acronym than the actual meaning (if one exists at all).

From the previous game, **MEC** (Mechanized Exoskeletal Cybersuit) is an acronym to denote what we generally call a "mech". I believe **EXALT** is an acronym too (from its capitalization), but its name seems to refer more to "exalted" than actually having a meaning to the acronym. Some people have offered that EXALT is named EXALT because they are the "**X**COM **alt**ernative", but no confirmation on whether that's the case or not.

**SHIVs** are the only ones I can think of that aren't as blatantly named (a shiv is not a robot but a makeshift knife). But even though it stands for "Super Heavy Infantry Vehicle", we never call them anything else than "shivs".

Even the name **XCOM** is a shortening for **X**eno **COM**mand. The game very much revels in the use of pseudo-military acronyms and concepts.

The same seems to apply to the suits in XCOM 2.

The **E.X.O. suit** is an external suit. Rather than mechanizing the unit from the inside like the MECs of XCOM, this is an external variant.
Insects have external skeletons, called **exoskeletons**... So they called the suit the "exo-suit". Making it into an acronym is just cosmetic, since we will only really use the acronym.

The **W.A.R.** suit seems obviously named.

Comment: Give your Ranger a WAR suit, then it's Well Armoured Ranger ;)

Comment: Sounds better than the Enhanced Xcom Operative suit I had him in first.

Comment: According to the [original X-Com: UFO Defense manual](http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/7760/manuals/x-com%20ufo%20defense%20manual.pdf?t=1447351440), X-Com stands for eXtraterrestrial COMbat unit (page 12).