# What is 'ADVENT' an abbreviation for?

Tags: xcom-2

In game the word itself is titled as all caps which leads me to assume that it's an abbreviation for something.

For example, X-COM (XCOM) is all caps, and stands for "E**x**traterrestrial **Com**bat Unit".

What does ADVENT stand for? Searched through the XCOM archives and have found no reference to what it exactly stand for.

Comment: "Advent" is an actual word though, unlike "XCOM". It means "the arrival of a notable person, thing, or event", according to Google.

Comment: Somewhat relevant http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/254897/what-do-the-acronyms-for-tier-2-and-tier-3-heavy-weapon-armors-stand-for

Comment: Aliens Deliberately Violating Earth and the Native Terrans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADVENT is [a word](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Advent) meaning **approach** or **arrival**. It also has significance in Christian cultures, where [Advent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advent) is the season before Christmas, where followers anticipate the coming of Christ.

As the plot of XCOM 2 unfolds, the Commander discovers that ADVENT forces are working towards...

> ...the completion of the Avatar Project.

The goal of this is to...

> ...create a new series of bodies for the Elders that are far more healthy than their decaying Ethereal ones. ([link](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Avatar_(XCOM_2)) - beware further spoilers)

I suspect the name ADVENT was deliberately chosen with this in mind, as...

> ...it reflects both the impending arrival of the Elders to Earth, and heralds their new Avatar forms whose advanced psionic powers could be viewed as godlike.

Comment: Though I like this thought, ADVENT have been a part of the series for far longer than XCOM2 was announced/planned. It seems unlikely that it was chosen with the plot-twists for the second game in mind.

Comment: Really? This is the first I'd heard of them. Where do they appear previously?

Comment: Oh, hell. Embarrassing - I'm thinking of EXALT, and apparently am very easily confused by five-six uppercase letters. I'm an idiot, sorry.

Comment: I did wonder, but no worries. :) Incidentally, I loved EXALT as a name - as a word it means to raise up or ennoble, which ties to their aims of evolving humanity using alien tech. More literally though, they're a secret human paramilitary organisation competing directly with XCOM - or an XCOM alternative. X-ALT. :D

Comment: EXALT actually sets a precedent for ADVENT here. Both seem to be acronyms, but are in reality chosen for its semantical meaning. EXALT sought to elevate themselves, ADVENT works to bring forth a new era. Very similar to a quote from Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.: _"What does S.H.I.E.L.D. stand for, Agent Ward?" "**Strategic Homeland Intervention, Enforcement and Logistics Division.**" "And what does that mean to you?" "**It means someone really wanted our initials to spell out "shield".**"_